# Getting Rugged::NetworkError on #connect

Tags: git, libgit2, rugged

I tried to implement fetch and this exception was raised:

> Rugged::NetworkError: This transport isn't implemented. Sorry

I am able to retrieve a remote instance:

```
remote = Rugged::Remote.lookup(repo, remote_name)
remote.connect(:fetch)
# => Rugged::NetworkError: This transport isn't implemented. Sorry
```

I retrieved the `development` version of the gem as directed in the README:

```
gem 'rugged', git: 'git://github.com/libgit2/rugged.git', branch: 'development', submodules: true
```

How do I gain access to the connect method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libgit2 uses openssl for HTTPS and libssh2 for ssh. You need the development packages for them in order for the embedded libgit2 to build with support for those transports.

Comment: I ran `brew install openssl libssh2` and same error. How precisely do should I download the packages?

Comment: @rhodee how did you figure this out? I ran the brew command, but `libgit2` still isn't (apparently) linking `libssh2` when it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on this, you need to install these:

```
openssl libssh2 libssl-dev pkg-config
```

Then you need to reinstall libgit2(rebuild), because the original shared libraries do not know that you've installed the new packages. See http://www.pygit2.org/install.html for installing.