# Can't clone repository with Rugged

Tags: ruby, rugged

Using openSUSE and Ubuntu with installed dependencies I can't clone the remote repository with `Rugged::Repository.clone_at` method and getting the error message:

> Rugged::NetworkError: This transport isn't implemented. Sorry

The code:

```
credentials = Rugged::Credentials::SshKey.new(:privatekey=>'path/to/privatekey', :publickey=>'path/to/publickey', :passphrase=>'passphrase')
Rugged::Repository.clone_at 'ssh://github.com/vmoravec/repo', 'dir/to/destination', :credentials => credentials
```

My Gemfile for a rails project contais reference to the github repo like this:

```
gem 'rugged', git: 'git://github.com/libgit2/rugged.git', branch: 'development', submodules: true
```

The gem has been installed with command `bundle install --path bundle/`
The cloning does not work even with using `bundle exec rails console`

Installed system packages:

- libssh2, libssh2-devel
- openssl, libopenssl-devel, libopenssl

There is already similar question asked here on SO, but the solution does not work (although it's for MacOS I think): [Getting Rugged::NetworkError on #connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255742/getting-ruggednetworkerror-on-connect)

Comment: Can you please link to the similar question and describe why that solution didn't work?

Comment: Check for what `ldd` reports about the `rugged.so` that comes out of the file to see if the build system was able to detect it. What transport are you using? What actual code leads to the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `bundle/` directory and reinstalling the gems with `bundle install --path bundle/` resolved the issue on both systems. It seems that the build system was not able for some reasons to detect the `/usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1` dependency required for `ssh` transport. Carlos, thanks for the hint to use `ldd rugged.so` to check that.